# What is counted as a Google Maps Android API request?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a premium account for Google maps API but I am seeing a lot of Google Maps Android API requests each day:

[image: Google Maps Android API requests in a day]

But I don´t have that many users who enter my map screen, I verified creating an analytics with firebase each time a user enters to this screen and the numbers are not the same (a lot less in firebase, around 150 daily). So there mush be another part of my app which is consuming credits. My question is, what other things besides looking at the map consume credits on the Google Maps Android API?. I use location tracking, I don´t know if that counts too, also I do autocomplete address, but no more than 30 times per day

Comment: [This](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/usage-limits) is the Premium Plan billing and usage rates. Static map load, street view image load, mobile SDK map load, autocomplete request and web service API calls all have separate counters/usage consumption.

Comment: Is it your Android application available publicly? I wonder why you need use map loads of your Premium license for Android app while the Standard plan Google Maps Android API has unlimited quota free of charge?

Comment: It´s the premium price as @ADimaano said, thanks a lot, for what I see tracking location and geofencing are not considered, I can work with that

Comment: The Premium plan users are entitled to technical support from Google as explained in https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/support#contact-support. You can file a support case to get precise answer from Google reps.